# GPU Compute not working on Cycles with RTX 3070

Tags: cycles-render-engine, gpu

My GPU Compute option is not rendering anything in viewport, or the final render. When I switch to CPU Compute, it works as intended, but I really would like to use my 3070 to do the work.

CPU compute on:
[image: CPU compute on:]

GPU compute on:
[image: GPU compute]

These are my preferences:
[image: Preferences]

Just ask if you need to know anything else!
Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: It is possible that the 30xx series of nvidia cards are having issues, given the frequent questions on this site. Try the latest version of blender or try upgrading or downgrading the drivers. If that doesn't work file a bug report.

Comment: Hi, santo, welcome. This is either a configuration problem, or a bug. Both are off-topic here. Please check configuration, drivers, as far as you can, and if no joy, make a bug report.